# If every covering of a topological space $X$ by basis elements has a countable subcovering, then $X$ is Lindelof.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I was attempting to prove this result about Lindelof spaces. Is the proof completely correct?Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Prove:If every covering of a topological space $X$ by basis elements has a countable subcovering, then $X$ is Lindelof.

Suppose that every covering of $X$ by basis elements in $\beta$ has a countable subcovering. Let $\{U_\gamma\}_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ be an open covering of $X$, by open sets in $X$. Then each $U_\gamma=\bigcup\limits_{B_\gamma \in \beta}B_\gamma$ is the union basis elements in $\beta$. So $X=\bigcup\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}U_\gamma=\bigcup\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}\bigcup\limits_{B_\gamma \in \beta}B_\gamma$. So $X$ is covered by a union of basis elements. So there is a countable subcollection $\{B_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements from $\beta$ covering $X$. Then by definition of a basis, each $B_n \subset U_n$ for some $U_n \in \{U_\gamma\}_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$. Thus the collection $\{U_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of all such $U_n$ is a countable collection of open sets in $X$ covering $X$.

I was worried about the correctness of some of my notation used, and was wondering what is the correct way to use the notation, if mine is incorrect.

Comment: Your proof is correct. I would say your notation is non-standard and a little bit confusing, but you do get your message across, which is the important thing. However, I would write the basis as $\mathcal{B} = \{B_i\}_{i \in I}$ and would then go on to say that for every $\gamma \in \Gamma$ there is a subset $I_\gamma \subseteq I$ such that $U_\gamma = \bigcup_{i \in I_\gamma} B_i.$

Comment: @ActuallyFritz So a better way to write the second equality would be $X=\bigcup\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}U_\gamma=\bigcup\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}\bigcup\limits_{i \in I_\gamma}B_i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not by the definition of a base that every $B_n \subset U_n$ etc. but because all $B_n$ are in some $B_\gamma$ which forms has as its union $U_\gamma$.

You could be more precise in your indexing notation and avoid confusion:

Let $\{U_\gamma\mid \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ be an open cover of $X$.

Write (here we use Choice (AC) quite heavily) $U_\gamma = \bigcup \mathcal{B}_\gamma$ where $\mathcal{B}_\gamma \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ where the latter family $\mathcal{B}$ is the given base. Then $\bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \mathcal{B}_\gamma$ is an open cover of $X$ by base elements, so there is a countable family $\mathcal{B}' \subseteq \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \mathcal{B}_\gamma$ that also covers $X$.
For each $B \in \mathcal{B}'$ we have $\gamma(B) \in \Gamma$ so that $B \in \mathcal{B}_\gamma$, and then $\{U_{\gamma(B)}\mid B \in \mathcal{B}'\}$ is a countable subcover, as is trivial to check.

We could also reason "pointwise" starting from the same cover : for each $x \in X$ we have $\gamma(x) \in \Gamma$ so that $x \in U_{\gamma(x)}$. As $\mathcal{B}$ is a base we have some $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ so that $x \in B_x \subseteq U_{\gamma(x)}$ (also heavy use of choice).
Then $\{B_x\mid x \in X\}$ is by construction an open cover by base elements so there is a countable subset $N$ of $X$ so that $\{B_x\mid x \in N\}$ also covers $X$. But then $\{U_{\gamma(x)}\mid x \in N\}$ is a countable subcover again.

Both write-ups show the "bookkeeping" involved to go back from a countable basic subcover to a countable general subcover.